# Conjugate of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Over an arbitrary ring $R$ with unit, is the matrix\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 & b & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 &0\\c & 0 & d &0\\ 0 &0&0&0
 \end{pmatrix}

conjugate over $GL(R)$ to 
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & 0&0\\
  c & d & 0&0\\0 & 0 &0 &0\\0&0&0&0
 \end{pmatrix}
?

Comment: Yes. It should be clear that they represent the same linear transformation but in different bases.

Comment: yeah, but I am sort of not able to write down the invertible matrix doing the conjugation...

Comment: Can you write down the correspondence between the bases? It's given by a change of basis matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View the matrices as linear maps to see that they are the same (one is the matrix of the other when we switch the second and third vectors). Thus take $$P:=\pmatrix{\mathbf 1_R&0&0&0\\ 0&0&\mathbf 1_R&0\\
0&\mathbf 1_R&0&0\\ 0&0&0&\mathbf 1_R},$$
where $\mathbf 1_R$ is the unit of $R$.

Answer (score 2):

You can get from one to the other by swapping the second and third rows and then the second and third columns. This corresponds to multiplying on the left by a certain row-switching matrix and then on the right by a certain column-switching matrix, as described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-switching_transformations). What are they? Note that such matrices are their own inverses.